# ¿Cómo guardo múltiples sesiones en un ciclo while de PHP?

Tags: php, array, session

Gusto en saludarles. En esta ocasión tengo un problema (quizá tonto) pero que me está volviendo loco. Tengo una consulta a la base de datos en donde con su correo extraigo algunos datos para poder guardarlos en una variable de sesión. El código que tengo es el siguiente:

```
    $prepare_sessions = "SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE correo = '$email' ";
    $make_q = $db->sql($prepare_sessions);

    while( $datos_sesion_usuario = mysqli_fetch_assoc($make_q) ) {
      $datos_usuario[] = array(
        'id_usuario' => $datos_sesion_usuario['ID'],
        'id_pais' => $datos_sesion_usuario['pais'],
        'nick_usuario' => $datos_sesion_usuario['nick'],
        'correo_usuario' => $datos_sesion_usuario['correo']
      );
    }

    foreach ($datos_usuario as $array_datos) {
        foreach ($array_datos as $key => $datos_usuario_valores) {
          $_SESSION[$key] = $datos_usuario_valores;
        }
    }
```

El problema es que cuando ejecuto el código, la página deja de responder y se tarda demasiado que me redirige a un error 404. Es bastante curioso, ya que si sólo tengo una variable de sesión y no muchas como en mi caso, funciona de maravilla.

Espero que puedan compartir alguna solución en base a su experiencia pronto. Gracias.

Answer (score 1):

Tu código siendo incompleto, voy a asumir que ya $db tiene tu conector a mysql e hiciste tu session_start() más arriba.

$db->sql no suena una función nativa de PHP, por lo cual me imagino también que has de usar alguna libreria externa para cargar el query, sin embargo justo después usas funciones de mysqli nativas. Este objeto $db de donde viene ? no tiene sus propias funciones para recuperar los datos de la base de datos ? quizás esto lo hace incompatible.

o primero que me salta es como agregas las variables a $_SESSION:
reemplazas los valores de cada renglon en cada loop, lo que es irrelevante.
Si quieres poner todos los datos en tu variable de sessión de hecho no necesitas el doble loop:

```
foreach ($datos_usuario as $array_datos) {
    foreach ($array_datos as $key => $datos_usuario_valores) {
      $_SESSION[$key] = $datos_usuario_valores;
    }
}
```

Actualmente $key contiene id_usuario, id_pais, etc.
Si quieres una variable por cada usuario más bien hazlo asi:

```
foreach ($datos_usuario as $array_datos) {
  $_SESSION[$array_datos['id_usuario']] = $array_datos;
}
```

y obtendrás una variable en $_SESSION por cada id de usuario.

---

Por otra parte, $email viene del exterior ? deberias de escaparlo para protegerte de las inyecciones SQL, o usar el operador de variable ? y enlazar la variable (ver manual de mysqli - PHP) http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php

$prepare_sessions = "SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE correo = ? ";

---

Es lo único que hace tu código ? o algo tiene atras que puede convertirse en 404 ? Porque si por ejemplo después tienes más código que usa las variables de sesión, o que hace un proceso complejo de datos etc, todo puede suceder después.

Saludos